# How can I use php to transform this url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have pages like this:

```
page.php?id=1&name=whatever
```

How could I transform this into...

```
page/1/whatever
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was being stupid. I used this...

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ page.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```